# References not working for \lstinputlisting

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, labels

I may be doing something wrong but can't realize what...

I want to set a label for a piece of code represented by:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, label={lst:control_os_call}, firstline=231, lastline=257]{./code/server.py}
```

so, I just try to link it using \ref

```
\ref{lst:control_os_call}
```

but I am getting a label missing error all the time (just for labels on `\lstinputlisting`). So... Should I import any specific package to reference those kind of labels or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Kindly add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) *always* as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `caption` thats all

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{server.py}
This is some python code
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=Python,caption={some python code}, label={lst:control_os_call}, firstline=1, lastline=257]{server.py}

Here is the code~\ref{lst:control_os_call}
\end{document}
```

[image]